# How can I access the companion object of a Scala class passed as a type param?

Tags: scala, generics, companion-object

I have a case class with companion object:

```
object Taco extends Dinner[Taco] {
  def ingredientNames: Seq[String] = Seq("filling", "cheese", "sauce")
}

case class Taco(filling: Meat, cheese: Cheese, sauce: Sauce) 
extends Dinner
```

And another one:

```
object Cheeseburger extends Dinner[Cheeseburger] {
  def ingredientNames: Seq[String] = Seq("cheese", "bun", "condiments")
}

case class CheeseBurger(cheese: Cheese, bun: Bun, condiments: Seq[Condiment]) 
extends Dinner[Cheeseburger]
```

I need to get ingredient names for these dinners before actually creating any dinner instances:

```
def printMenu[D <: Dinner[D]]: String = ???
```

How can I access the companion object of a `Dinner` subclass?

Comment: Why does the companion object `Taco` extend `Dinner[Taco]`? That shouldn't be, because the case class `Taco` already extends `Dinner[Taco]` (it's a typo, I assume? There cannot be two different classes `Dinner` with different arities).

Comment: @Andrey - I believe both object and case class can extend `Dinner` like this, because `Dinner` has zero arity. (Right?) However, I'm not actually claiming that's a good idea.

Comment: No, `Dinner[Taco]` needs arity `1`, whereas `Dinner` needs arity `0`. They cannot coexist in same scope.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Are you referring to the `printMenu` part? That should have read `D <: Dinner[D]` -- just edited to fix that. Hopefully we agree that `Dinner` now always has arity 1. (Assuming that the type param is considered part of the arity, which I suppose must be the case. But maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by arity here.)

Comment: No, I referred to `class Taco extends Dinner`. It still has arity `0`. It should be `class Taco extends Dinner[Taco]`.

Answer (score 4):

Type classes to the rescue:

```
trait Dinner { ... }
trait DinnerCompanion[A <: Dinner] {
  implicit def self: DinnerCompanion[A] = this
  def ingredientNames: Seq[String]
  ...
}

object Taco extends DinnerCompanion[Taco] {
  def ingredientNames: Seq[String] = Seq("filling", "cheese", "sauce")
}

case class Taco(filling: Meat, cheese: Cheese, sauce: Sauce) extends Dinner

def printMenu[A <: Dinner](implicit companion: DinnerCompanion[A]): String = 
  companion.ingredientNames.mkString(", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the following construction (inspired by `GenericCompanion` from the standard collection library):

```
type Condiment = String
type Meat = String
type Cheese = String
type Sauce = String
type Bun = String


trait Dinner[A] {
  def companion: DinnerCompanion[A]
}

trait DinnerCompanion[A] {
  def ingredientNames: Seq[String]
}

case class Taco(filling: Meat, cheese: Cheese, sauce: Sauce) 
extends Dinner[Taco] {
  def companion = Taco
}

implicit object Taco extends DinnerCompanion[Taco] {
  def ingredientNames: Seq[String] = Seq("filling", "cheese", "sauce")
}

case class CheeseBurger(cheese: Cheese, bun: Bun, condiments: Seq[Condiment]) 
extends Dinner[CheeseBurger] {
  def companion = CheeseBurger
}

implicit object CheeseBurger extends DinnerCompanion[CheeseBurger] {
  def ingredientNames: Seq[String] = Seq("cheese", "bun", "condiments")
}

def printMenu[D: DinnerCompanion]: String = 
  implicitly[DinnerCompanion[D]].ingredientNames.mkString
```

Now every instance of a `Dinner` has method `companion`, and the `companion` in turn has `ingredientNames`.

**EDIT** added `printMenu` (has nothing to do with companion objects whatsoever, uses `object Taco` and `object CheeseBurger` as ordinary typeclass instances).

Comment: This is great, and gets me halfway there -- however, it still requires I have an instance of `Dinner` before I can get to the companion. My goal is to get to `Taco.ingredientNames` without actually having a `Taco` instance, just the type `Taco` passed as a type param. E.g., `printMenu[D <: Dinner]`.

Comment: @Sasgorilla added `printMenu`. It now doesn't depend in any way on anything being a companion object of anything else, so I'm not sure why you added all the Meat/Cheese/Sauce/Bun and all the other stuff to your question.

Comment: Your `printMenu` will need to be called as `printMenu[Taco.type]` (or `printMenu(Taco)`), not `printMenu[Taco]`. Though that can be fixed.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yeah, you're right, fixed. Appended the last method without much thinking, I thought that the emphasis of the question was on something else entirely. Too many tacos.